# Order by sequence number in case - possibility

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I got a little bit complicated report in sql for my HR dep. and one of fields is that if someone got social insurance. 
a must have case for it ( if some assumptions are met then view Yes otherwise No ) the problem is that people are employyed more then one time and not always want to have social insurance.

the data looks like:

```
https://fojlww.am.files.1drv.com/y4mawp7Xs7HahMkb_h_bP7xuD_UIHAfDF3dvZ1iPLD5kGMFjHpcJpEDUD3g8TyNmT5mxgZbU6LLJPhWGivDtZEy8i4e3lz32jMBIB7yw5MzRO4U5PiGdoWtbIT02Qdk-9_eGfxTUgkGcE-g4JNQ80C6TK2PSUmlIzBlTmo99knOJotmSnLbqJevrF5CB3jmdKtLVGEfdDY4dLHoCcnWWZV10Q?width=1306&height=320&cropmode=none
```

```
(CASE WHEN (select s.emp_no from SSI_DATA s where 
s.C_NO_CONTRIBUTIONS = 'FALSE' and  OBLIG_PENSION_INSUR = 'TRUE' and s.emp_no = cp.emp_no and s.company_id = cp.company_id and 
(s.C_NO_CONTRIB_SINCE <= '2019-10-10' or s.C_NO_CONTRIB_SINCE is null or s.C_NO_CONTRIB_SINCE = 'FALSE' ) and  rownum = 1 
<p>order by s.seq desc</p>
--and s.seq = ( select max(seq) from SSI_DATA where emp_no = cp.emp_no and company_id = cp.company_id)
) = cp.emp_no 

THEN 'Y'

ELSE 'N' END)
```

Comment: Please post your sample data as text and your expected result as text.

Comment: seems `C_NO_CONTRIB_SINCE` is not a date type column but sometimes stores date-alike values. It's not a good design.

Comment: about C_NO_CONTRIB_SINCE i know that but that was designed few years ago ...

Comment: Actually it was "not designed" a few years ago. Anyhow, I think the *SELECT statement inside a CASE statement* is the wrong approach. Probably you should select from SSI_DATA in a derived view (with different logic instead of ROWNUM which doesn't work the way you seem to think it does), and use an OUTER JOIN on `cp.emp_no `. Then your column becomes a `NVL2()` test on `s.empno`.  Without seeing the data model it's hard to be sure what the correct approach is. However, if `C_NO_CONTRIB_SINCE` is representative I'm quite happy to not see the data model. I'm sure it would only make me sad.